# What characteristic of the triangle leads the the existence of the orthocenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

We all know that all three altitudes of a triangle meets in the orthocenter of the triangle. It's a quite classical problem and is proven.
However, what I really wanna know is what characteristic of the triangle is the profound for this to happen? 
E.g: Is this because of the sum of 3 internal angles equals 180? In Non-Euclidean geometry, where sum of 3 internal angles is greater or smaller than 180 degree, does the 3 altitudes meets in a single point?
Or is it because of another reason?

Comment: Euler has quite a few things named after him, so there is no need to deprive Euclid of any honors! :D

Comment: In the hyperbolic plane, the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle can be concurrent, have a common perpendicular or be asymptotic. In general, then, there is no orthocenter.

Comment: Have you heard, that the orthocenter is isogonal conjugate of circumcentre? It does not explain everything about the orthocenter, but for me it does explain a lot (isogonal conjugation contains traces of $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ transformation).

Comment: Something else that bothers me more is that the existence of the Euler line: the orthocenter, centroid, and circumcenter of any triangle are always collinear. It sounds interesting but doesn't it seem a little bit coincident? I mean I know how to prove it but it doesn't sound natural to me.

Comment: I remember my Physics teacher once tell me about the meaning of numbers: The real numbers forms a perfect continuous line called the Real axis. However no matter how perfect it is, it only like a crack in the wall, which means it's one dimensional, it's the image of the one dimension space. And then they invent the imaginary numbers, which forms another different axis from the Real ones. Together they form the 2 dimensions space, which is better. And they have matrix, which can describe a fully n-dimension space (we all know that a 2x2 matrix is enough to display a Complex number).

Comment: Knowing all this, the matrix concept sounds natural to me, at least it reflects something real and we can predict the behavior of the matrix by observing the real one. However this leads me to a thinking that might sound stupid but do you really think the triangle is "natural" in a way that it reflect some real thing in the universe? (I know that we have a lot of triangle in everyday life but isn't it all man-made? Without the existing of human, would there be any real triangles? Does it sound like something that we just made up ourselves?

Comment: @NhímHổBáo The triangle inequality (in whatever space) isn't man-made, the shortest-paths problem is intrinsic to the world.

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps interesting to note that the definition of altitudes is perfectly straightforward for simplexes in higher dimensions, but that already in dimension $3$ the altitudes of a general tetrahedron are not concurrent. For instance for the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$, two of the altitudes meet in the origin and two others meet in $(1,0,0)$, but there are no other points of intersection; in general position none of the altitudes will intersect.

Answer (score 1):

The proofs I know all use Euklidean geometry (e.g. the orthocenter is the intersection of the middle orthogonals for a bigger triangle).

In synthetic geometry, one can consider translation planes with an orthogonality relation and the Fano axiom (diagonals of a nondegenerate parallelogram intersect), thus minimally allowing the proof above. One can show that this makes the geometry at least a Pappus plane.

Comment: What is  synthetic geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir Arnol'd often emphasized that it was because of the Jacobi identity in Lie algebras.  I think he might have meant the algebra so(3) represented as $R^3$ with vector cross-product as the multiplication, but am not sure, and it would be nice to see his remark explained.